# Single line using write and read of streams Java

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I saw like this, always :

```
int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
if (count > 0) {
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Other example

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Adjust if you want
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

other...

```
  int numRead;
  while ( (numRead = is.read(buf) ) >= 0) {
      os.write(buf, 0, numRead);
  }
```

I never saw something like this:

```
  while (true) {
    try {
      output.write(BytesArray, 0, input.read(BytesArray, 0, BytesArray.length)); //Single line for read and write!!!!
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I can't write!");
        break;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("I can't read!");
        break;
    }
  }
```

What's the problem to use a OuputStream Writing somethig readed by InputStream recently read?

Is there some problem?

**EDIT**
`InputStream.read` works precisely when `OutputStream.write` works, and fails when the other also fails; in the same way `OutputStream.write` works when `InputStream.read` so does and stops when the other also fails to do so.

When `InputStream.read(...)` fails (or can not read more) this method returns `-1`; but, when `OutputStream.write(...)` fails (or can not write more) this method throws an `IOException` exception.

I personally believe that: when `OutputStream.write(...)` can't write  should to return "-1"exactly the same way the `InputStream.read(...)` does when can not read.

**QUESTION:** 
*believe you that `InputStream.read(...)` and `OutputStream.write(...)`  they should be handled in the same manner (both returns `-1`)?*

NOTE:  I know this method for OutputStream: `public void write(...)`

Comment: Using exception handling to perform control flow - especially when it is unnecessary because of the API - is bad practice.

Comment: "Single line for read and write!!!!" Shame about all the other extra lines though.

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you Andy, when the `InputStream.read(...)` returns `-1` the  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  will be thrown, then is neccessary to separate the lines for read and write. But what is the alternative to `catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)` using only one single line?

Comment: Sometimes you just can't (or shouldn't try to) write things a single line. I'd hardly count having to handle an exception as "a single line".

Comment: Sorry @AndyTurner, but following on direction to your comment... I have this question: How to detect when `OutputStream.write(...) fail if not using an exception?`    as far as I know it is mandatory to use `catch (IOException e)`, but that would be a bad practice according to your first comment.   What choice do I have in this case without proving the occurrence of a particular exception?

Comment: What you are confusing is the difference between the read or write *failing* (which is an actual exceptional condition, and thus is an appropriate use of an exception) and reaching the end of the input stream (which is *not* an exceptional condition, since pretty much all streams end, and thus is not an appropriate use of an exception, nor is it a necessary use of an exception, since it is detectable via the return values of `read`). The `IOException` must be caught (or thrown); the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is simply the result of careless use of the API.

Comment: It is also worth noting that `IOException` is a checked exception, whereas `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is an unchecked exception. Checked exceptions *must* be handled, because they are designed to indicate recoverable conditions (e.g. "try writing this data again later, it might succeed when the disk has more free space"); unchecked exceptions do not need to be handled because they are designed to indicate *unrecoverable* conditions, like programming errors (e.g. "you can try running this code again later, but it'll fail again because of the same bug"). (cont)

Comment: As such, relying upon *unchecked exceptions* for your control flow, whilst possible, is *not* what they are designed for.

Comment: What benefit justifies the cost? The costs being poor readability, expensive flow control, and poor exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

Using exception handling to perform control flow - when it is unnecessary because of the API - is bad practice.

If your reason for wanting to do so is so that you can write statements on one line, you should evaluate the reasons why you think it is better to write the statements on one line. My phone has a large enough screen on it to display all four examples above at the same time - and I don't code on my phone - so I can't imagine a situation where writing something on a single line "because I can write it on a single line" is a compelling-enough reason.

Also, consider whether the fact that you are able to write *some* of the statements on a single line really makes the code shorter overall:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    output.write(buffer, 0, input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
  } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    break;
  }
}
```

(I am ignoring the `IOException` here, as you have in the first 3 examples - it needs to be handled however you write the code, so it is irrelevant to the difference between the 4 versions in terms of quantity of code).

Compare this to the equivalent code from approach 2 (the closest equivalent):

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Which is a lot more concise.

But, as I have alluded to above, brevity of code is not really a measure of quality of code, so in and of itself, this is not a reason to dismiss the proposed version just yet. However, there are more fundamental reasons why it is not a good approach...

---

In the proposed code, there are two expected types of exception: `IOException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. These are exceptions of a fundamentally different nature:

- The `IOException` is expected to result from a read or write *failing* (which is an actual exceptional condition, and thus is an appropriate use of an exception).

  `IOException` is a *checked* exception. Checked exceptions must be handled (it is a compile-time error not to). They are designed to indicate recoverable conditions and conditions which are beyond the control of the API. For instance, if you are writing to the disk or network, you have no control over whether the disk is being filled up by another process, or if the contractors digging up the road are about to cut your fiber connection. Checked exceptions indicate "this might succeed if you try again later" (when the disk isn't as full, or the contractors have fixed the fiber)
- The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is expected to result from reaching the end of the input stream (which is not an exceptional condition, since pretty much all streams end, and thus is not an appropriate use of an exception, nor is it a necessary use of an exception, since it is detectable via the return values of read).

  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is an *unchecked* exception, which results from a programming error - using the API in a way which it is not intended to be used. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be handled (it is not a compile-time error if you don't) because they are designed to indicate mostly *unrecoverable* conditions, like programming errors. For instance, if you try running some code with a particular input and it throws an unchecked exception because of a programming bug, it will throw the same unchecked exception later because it's running the same code.

As such, *whilst you can* catch and recover from unchecked exceptions, that is *not* what they were designed for (which is why you don't *have* to). It is easier to write the code so that the exception doesn't occur in the first place.

And that's easy in this case: the [Javadoc for `OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)) says:

> If `off` is negative, or `len` is negative, or `off+len` is greater than the length of the array `b`, then an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

So, meet these conditions, and you don't have to worry about it happening.

(And you'd need to have been catching `IndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` anyway, because some implementations of `OutputStream` may not throw the latter.)

But there is a deeper reason why you shouldn't rely upon catching unchecked exceptions for your control flow: *you might not be detecting the condition you think you are*.

An unchecked exception of any type can be thrown from anywhere in the call chain of a particular call - you might *expect* that it is occurring because `OutputStream.write` doesn't like a negative `len` parameter, but it can *actually* be called by anything else in `OutputStream.write` - or in `InputStream.read` - or in any of the other methods that they call transitively - you can't tell for sure (without inspecting the stack trace; however, the details of what you should inspect the stack trace for are implementation-specific, and thus it would take a lot of effort to make this robust enough).

If you treat this exception as meaning you've reached the end of the stream, you might actually be masking some other problem in the code that you *want* to know about.

So, the best thing to do is to write your code so that it *does not* rely upon catching a specific unchecked exception. Where it is documented that it will throw such an exception under specific circumstances, *avoid those circumstances*.